# How to get value from Count SQL statement query with pgx driver (Golang)

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I failing to understand why I can not scan single value to "count" variable.
Could anyone explain what am i doing wrong? Single column value is returned and I try to scan it to integer variable.

```golang
query := `
SELECT COUNT('*') FROM "some-table"
WHERE (("state" = 'state') AND ("id" = 1))`

rows, err := s.conn.Query(ctx, query)
defer rows.Close()
var count int
err = rows.Scan(&count)
if err != nil {
    return false, fmt.Errorf("execute query: %w", err)
    }
```

Returns error:
`execute query: number of field descriptions must equal number of values, got 1 and 0"`

UPDATE:
I made workaround with thing below, but not sure it the right way:

```golang
count, err := pgx.CollectOneRow(rows, pgx.RowTo[int])
```

Comment: remove the double quotes around the count paylod

Comment: changed here for single quotes. it's valid query and returns expected result in psql CLI. furthermore its for demo purpouses. i use goqu go build queries

Comment: there can't be any quotes, this will search for the string * the coamnd is `COUNT(*)` without any quotes at all

Comment: if don't bileve me and you know better and you have time you can go and test by yourself. I have 1 colum count with result in cell.

Comment: In PostgreSQL double quotes delimit identifiers, single quotes represent a string constant. `SELECT COUNT("*") FROM "some-table"` can work ONLY IF `some-table` has a column named `*` (which is possible but not recommended). `SELECT COUNT('*') FROM "some-table"` will work just fine, however this is unconventional and smells. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "some-table"` is the most common variant.

Comment: Note that, when executing queries that return a single row, it is recommended to use `QueryRow` instead of `Query`... Regarding the error; my guess is that the reason you are having problems with your query is because you are using `Query` and then `Scan` but **without first calling `Next`** in between. Note also that doing `defer rows.Close()` before checking the error returned by `Query` is going to crash your program eventually. **In 99% of cases, you should never touch the primary return value of a function/method call before first checking the error return value.**